# MySQL Query Improvement (Tmp table, Sending data & Sorting)

Tags: mysql, performance

My query looks like this:

```
    SELECT Sender, Recipient, Sent 
FROM 
     (SELECT Sender, Recipient, Sent FROM prv_chat WHERE 100 IN (Sender, Recipient)) 
     AS chat 
GROUP BY Sender, Recipient 
ORDER BY Sent DESC LIMIT 30
```

The purpose of it is to search for all chat messages that a specific User (in this case the User with the ID 100) sent or received  (`inner query`)

This query is run quite frequently on my server and takes up a lot of time (`>0.1s`)
The phpMyAdmin analyzing tool shows that ~32% of the time is taken by `Copying to tmp table` (I guess it's caused by the inner query), ~30% by `Sending data` (Missing indexes?) and another 30% by `Sorting results`

`DESCRIBING` the query tells me that it's not using any indexes (although that it says that  there are possible indexes)

Here is the full list:
[image: Indexes]

Anyone got a clue?

**EDIT:**

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE prv_chat

CREATE TABLE `prv_chat` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Sender` int(9) NOT NULL,
 `Recipient` int(9) NOT NULL,
 `Chat` text NOT NULL,
 `Sent` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `Sender` (`Sender`,`Recipient`),
 KEY `Sent` (`Sent`),
 KEY `Sender_3` (`Sender`,`Recipient`,`Sent`),
 KEY `Sender_2` (`Sender`,`Sent`),
 KEY `Recipient` (`Recipient`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=125082 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EDIT2:** I edited the query and the `sorting results` part is elimated now.
Though the `Sending results` and the `Copying to tmpo table` progress still takes up a lot of time

**EDIT3:** Changed the query again. Now the only part that takes up much time is `Sending data`
`DESCRIBE` returns this:
[image: DESCRIBE]

**EDIT 4:** `DESCRIBE` for Xint0's query:
[image: DESCRINE 2]

Comment: Can you post the DDL for `prv_chat`?

Comment: I added it to the first post

Answer (score 0):

The operator `OR` makes mysql ignore an index. Try instead:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *  FROM prv_chat WHERE Sender=100 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *  FROM prv_chat WHERE Recipient=100 
) AS chat
ORDER BY Sent DESC LIMIT 30; --done by hand, may not run
```

Comment: Thank you, that eliminates the big `Sorting results` part. But I'm still having trouble with `Sending data` (now 90%) and `Copying to tmp table`

Comment: What is the rowcount of the table and of this query without the limit?

Comment: Can you run DESCRIBE on the query and post the result?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Logical error in query design. Providing new suggestion for sub-query

```
SELECT *
FROM prv_chat 
WHERE 100 IN (Sender, Recipient) 
ORDER BY Sent DESC;
```

That should work for what you're currently retrieving.

This `100 IN (Sender, Recipient)` bit will also utilize your `Sender_3` key

EDIT: You may also want to look at the `InnoDB` engine for your table

Comment: Oh, well, this seems to work as well for the sorting part. Actually I have no idea why this inner query was necessary when I wrote the query, but it didn't work without it. But your solutions works for this problem, too!

Comment: But when I'm trying to GROUP it now by the `Sender, Recipient`, the query slows down by a lot again (Copying to tmp table)

Comment: Why are you grouping?

Comment: Because your query returns the same Sender-Recipient combination multiple times. What I need is actually `DISTINCT (Sender, Recipient) WITH NEWEST Sent`

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest using `WHERE 100 IN (Sender, Recipient)` instead of your initial `OR` statement and use that as the sub-query

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently trying to convert my Table to InnoDB and I'll try your suggestion afterwards. And I also think I found out what's causing the `Copying to tmp table` progress: The `prv_chat` table contains a text column (`Chat`) which has a high data volume. I guess selecting * in the inner query makes MySQL copying all of these chat messages, too

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, you can `SELECT DISTINCT Sender, Recipient, MAX(Date)` (should eliminate duplicates). (Note: This just uses MySQL's optimizer for grouping / aggregating / distinct)

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't really help with my improved query (look at the first post). Your solution with MAX(Sent) somehow only returns one row

Comment: The group by part should be in there =P

Comment: Aaand as an afterthought, that doesn't change too much from your original query

Comment: You mean putting the group part in the `inner query`? That somehow makes the query even slower (by a little bit)

Comment: Well, looking back on this comment chain, I would strongly suggest that I don't make any suggestions while sleep-deprived. Let me know how InnoDB performs

Comment: Unfortunatelly it was still pretty slow, even after trying all of these suggestions. Yesterday I thought about creating a special table that contains only the data about the Sender, Recipient and the timestamp of the last message. This requires an additional Update/Insert query everytime someone sends a chat message, but it takes only 0.0004 for reading query. So... I guess that's the only possible solution for this problem. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

As you noted on a comment, the problem is selecting all columns using `*`.  As a general recommendation, try not to select all columns if not needed.

I would suggest:

```
select Sender, Recipient, MaxSent
from (
    select pc.Sender, pc.Recipient, max(pc.Sent) as MaxSent
    from
        prv_chat pc
        inner join (
            select ID from prv_chat where Sender = 100
            union
            select ID from prv_chat where Recipient = 100
        ) f on pc.ID = f.ID
    group by pc.Sender, pc.Recipient
) g
order by MaxSent desc limit 100;
```

That way subquery `f` filters IDs by Sender and Recipient and uses the corresponding indexes.

Then subquery `g` groups by Sender, Recipient and gets the maximum Sent value, should use index Sender_3.

The outer query only orders the filtered and grouped results.

**EDIT**

After seeing the `DESCRIBE` output, it seems the `g` subquery is not using the `Sender_3` index.  I would suggest first to run `analyze table prv_chat;` command to update index statistics so the MySQL engine can optimize the query based on current index coverage.  If that does not result in the engine using `Sender_3` index, then try modifying it to include `ID` as the first column: `(ID, Sender, Recipient, Sent)`.

**EDIT2**

I think the temporary table and filesort are caused by sorting on the aggregate result.

Comment: Thank you, this query seems to work perfectly well :) And the performance is also better. Still the `Copying to tmp table` takes up more than 0.04s approximatelly. Any ideas? --- I'll post the `DESCRIBE` results for this query in a moment

Comment: Thank you, I tried both new suggestions, but it didn't change anything. Index `Sender_3` is still not being used by the query.